# WPF: Set a trigger on a ContextMenu if one of its children is clicked - or not?

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I would like to indicate to users if a sub-menu (or sub-sub-menu) is checked from the first level of a [`MenuItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.menuitem(v=vs.110).aspx) in a [`ContextMenu`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contextmenu(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1).

Is this possible ?

I tried with this:

```
    /// <summary>Coloriser les éléments d'un ContextMenu qui ont des enfants coches</summary>
public bool FormatContextMenu(ItemCollection pIc) {
    var ret = false;
    foreach (var item in pIc.OfType<MenuItem>()) {
        if (item.IsChecked) ret = true;
        if (((MenuItem)item).Items?.Count>0) {
            var b = FormatContextMenu(item.Items);
            if (b) {
                item.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(200, 200, 200));
                ret = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

That's working but it not dynamic and not MVVM.
I have to call it on each display with:

```
FormatContextMenu(cmuFiltresAll.Items);
```

If possible, I like to make it without code behind... Only Xaml.

Comment: Everything is possible, almost ;)
What have you tried? Were do you stuck?

Comment: I have just edited my post for more information.

Comment: If your ContextMenu has ItemsSource that is binded to a collection, you keep everything MVVM. By way of binding the IsChecked of the CheckBox to a bool on your data item side.